# react - what is the right way to manage ckeditor if I want to add some custom plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor and I am wondering what is the right way to manage the it in `React.JS`.

**My current workaround**
I am following [this tutorial](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html) to install ckeditor to my project by running `npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic`.

In App.js

```
return(
  <CKEditor
                    editor={ ClassicEditor }
                    config={
                        {
                            toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'blockQuote', 'link', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'imageUpload', 'insertTable',
                            'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo'],
                            heading: {
                                options: [
                                    { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                                    { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                                    { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    data={content}
                    onReady={ editor => {
                        console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                    } }
                    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                        const data = editor.getData();
                        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                    } }
            />
)
```

After that, I find that I need to use `insert image` function which require plugin `Base64 image upload adapter`.

I am thinking of using below way do it after I've made some research:

Download the `ckeditor5-build-classic-stable` and modify `src/ckeditor.js` according to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@jacobtamus/ckeditor5-custom-react-editor-tutorial-a9e91aab9d16), and then let it refer to my node_modules in my project.**
But I find it having some drawbacks, such as requiring to run `npm run build` when I want to view the changes.

Any suggestions?